# Redirecting logs based on variables for the directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have a `bash` script like below. I want to redirect the logs to a specific directory based on the server where the script is running.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Host name of server
host=hostname

if [ "$host" == "XXXXXXX.com" ];then
        logs=devlogs
else
        logs=logs
fi

do something  > /home/$USER/"${logs}"/abc_"${Date}" 2>&1
```

Here in the script If the server is `XXXXXXX.com` I want to store the logs in `/home/$USER/devlogs/abc_"${Date}"` else `/home/$USER/logs/abc_"${Date}"`

But even when the server is `XXXXXXX,com` the logs are still being stored in `/home/$USER/logs/abc_"${Date}"`

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: FYI, `==` isn't guaranteed to work if your code is run with `sh` rather than `bash`. Safer to change it to `[ "$host" = "XXXXXX.com" ]`, with only one `=`.

Comment: Also, use `set -x` to log your script -- in that case, you'd see `[ hostname == XXXXXX.com ]` instead of `[ whatever.com = XXXXXX.com ]`, which would be a pretty good hint as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unable to find the `hostname` correctly. Use like below to find

```
host=$(hostname)
```

Then when your hostname is `XXXXXXX.com`

```
if [ "$host" == "XXXXXXX.com" ]
```

will become

```
if [ "XXXXXXX.com" == "XXXXXXX.com" ]
```

Then you will be able to achieve what you want

Comment: If that's the issue, the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash and should be closed as such; see the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" heading within [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).